Can I install AMD AOCC Fortran 4.2 on Windows 11?
Can I install the AOCC Fortran compiler AMD 4.2 on Windows 11? The documentation doesn't explicitly state that it is unsupported on Windows, but the user guide also doesn't provide any installation instructions for the Windows platform.

AOCC Fortran does not support Windows

A very quick search of the web using the keywords you've provided gave me a very first result of AMD's own documentation on this product. The first line in the first section past the intro of that document says this:

AOCC offers many features, notably:
For applications targeting 32-bit and 64-bit Linux® platforms

That is pretty explicit.
